# api-blueprint how to referance to definied HOST

Tags: apiblueprint

I am a new user of api-blueprint. I can't find how to reference to the defined HOST in the 2nd line of the document. I want to achieve the combination of the HOST address and the endpoint like this:

```
HOST: https://www.mybaseurl.com
###API Request Example
url: {{HOST}}/v1/api/token?key=partnerKey&secret=partnerSecret
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer how to define an endpoint with a usage of a HOST is as below:

```
FORMAT: 1A
HOST: https://www.mybaseurl.com

# Name your API

## Group API Requests

## API Request Example [/v1/api/token?{key,secret}]

+ Parameters

    + key: partnerKey (string) - An unique identifier of the partner
    + secret: partnerSecret (string) - An secret of the partner

### Name of the action using the following HTTP method in brackets [GET]

+ Request Plain Text Message

    + Headers

            Accept: text/plain

+ Response 200 (text/plain)

    + Headers

            X-My-Message-Header: 42

    + Body

            Hello World!
```